# Translating elements and adding enumeration IDs using Jinja2 templates?

Tags: python, jinja2

I am creating pages that display slides from a slideshow (which are stored as images called slide001.png, slide002.png, etc.) along with transcripts of the voiceover. The templates look like this:

> <div class="transcript">
>     <p>Hello, and welcome to the first slide.</p>
>     <p>This is the second slide.</p>
>     <p>/...and so on...</p>
>   </div>

I want this translated into:

> <div class="transcript">
>     <div class="slide">
>       <img src="slide001.png"/>
>       <p>Hello, and welcome to the first slide.</p>
>     </div>
>     ...and so on for each slide...
>   </div>

i.e., each paragraph is wrapped in a div, and an img element is inserted with a consecutively-numbered image reference.  I'm doing this with JavaScript right now, but since I'm using Jinja2 to do other things (insert consistent headers and footers, creating forward/back links, etc.), I was hoping I could do the wrap-and-enumerate in Jinja2 as well. Is it possible without heroic hackery?

Comment: Yes, if you show us the actual template, what you showed is just the generated html and useless.

Comment: If I had the template, I wouldn't have needed to post the question :-)  What I have is the HTML I'm starting with, that I want to _convert_ to a template, and the desired output; what I need is the templating that'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the data into the following format in your page then it can be rendered quite nicely.

```
transcript = [{'image': 'filepath', 'text':'welcome...'},
              {'image': 'filepath2', 'text':'slide2'},
              {'image': 'filepath3', 'text':'slide3'}]
```

The Jinja can placed inline or moved to a macro but this will do the trick either way:

```
<div class="transcript">
  {% for slide in transcript %}
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="{{ slide.image }}"/>
    <p>{{ slide.text }}</p>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```